# Como fazer com que o gráfico do Highcharts sempre mostre o PlotLines?

Tags: highcharts

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que o gráfico se baseie no valor do `PlotLines`, sem setar um tamanho mínimo e máximo para o gráfico. Por exemplo, tenho um PlotLine pro eixo X de valor 30 e outro pro eixo Y de valor 70. Não defini valor máximo, nem mínimo para o gráfico, mas quando tenho um ponto por exemplo, com os eixos menores que o valor dos PlotLines, ele não exibe.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obs: Uso o Gráfico **Scatter**

Segue abaixo o código dos eixos X e Y:

```
xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Audit e DDD'
            },
            //max: 200,
            //min: -200,
            //startOnTick: true,
            //tickInterval: 50,                
            //endOnTick: true,                
            showLastLabel: true,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            plotLines:[{
                value: 70,
                color: 'red',
                width: 1,
                label:{
                    text: '70',
                    align: 'left'
                }
            }] 
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {   
                enabled: true,             
                text: 'Visitação e conhecimento'
            },
            //max: 200,
            //min: -200,
            //startOnTick: true,
            //tickInterval: 50,                
            //endOnTick: true,                
            showLastLabel: true,
            plotLines:[{
                value: 30,
                color: 'blue',
                width: 1,
                label:{
                    text: '30',
                    align: 'left'

                }                    
            }]                
        },
```

Comment: Poste o código que já tem tentado, ajuda a nós te ajudarmos.

Comment: @Marconi Coloquei o código dos eixos X e Y.

Comment: Qual é o tipo de gráfico que tem usado?

Comment: @Marconi Uso o Scatter

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVIDO**

Resolvi o problema adicionando uma série inicial, já que meus dados são dinâmicos, setando os valores dos eixos que correspondem a cada valor do plotLine, um pro X e outro pro Y, deste modo, ele sempre vai carregar o gráfico com os plotLines definidos.